# how do I enable video .mpd and widevine in samsung smart tv?

Tags: javascript, video, samsung-smart-tv, drm, widevine

I develop app for samsung smart tv. Need to play dash and widevine video. I get from the server mpd and licenseUrl.
I tried use:
Shaka Player, dash.js, video-js - each of these players I was able to run videos in browser, but not on the smartTV app.
Shaka Player i use to start the video at tizen tv.

also i use

1. it works for video without widevine

   `function getESN() {
       var deviceId = null;
       try {
           var deviceId = document.getElementById("externalPlugin").GetESN("WIDEVINE");
           if (!deviceId) {
               throw new Exception('GetESN is not supported. Please reboot the device and call to Samsung service center if the issue happens again.');
           }
           if ((deviceId + '').substr(0, Math.min(deviceId.length, 2)) != 'SS') {
               throw new Exception('deviceId is not valid. Please reboot the device and call to Samsung service center if the issue happens again.');
           }
       } catch (e) {
           alert("EXCEPTION(getESN):" + e);
           return null;
       }
       return deviceId;
   }
   var deviceId = getESN();
   var url = 'urlToMpd|DEVICE_ID=' + deviceId + '|DEVICET_TYPE_ID=60|DRM_URL=licenseUrl|COMPONENT=HAS';
   var player = document.getElementById('pluginPlayer');
   player(url)`

if you change in the url 'COMPONENT=WV' video will not work.

2. samsung sent me an example AVPlay player and the video works there, but url not like I have

url: "http://***.wvm"

and I need

url: "http://***.mpd"

how do I enable video .mpd and widevine in samsung smart tv?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Specs](https://www.samsungdforum.com/Tizen/Spec#GeneralFeatures) you have to use real TV device to test/play widevine DRM, Emulator doesn't supports widevine.

you may use [AVPLay API](https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenApiGuide/tizen3001/index.html#AVPlay-AVPlayManager-setDrm) to play widevine DRM. Check out SamsungDForum , A sample widevine play application is is provided here:

[TizenSampleGuide PlayerAVPlayDRM](https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenSampleGuide/tizen4611/index.html)

github link of the sample application: [github link](https://github.com/SamsungDForum/PlayerAVPlayDRMhttp://)

Playing DASH .mpd format requires 
[Adaptive Streaming](https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/tizen3971/index.html)

You may follow the [TVDemoAvPlayer](https://github.com/Samsung/TizenTVApps/tree/master/TVDemoAvPlayer) app from this [git repository](https://github.com/Samsung/TizenTVApps)